# Expected symbol priority

Tags: discrete-mathematics, operator-theory, expected-value

About the expected priority of operations. For example:

$C-E[x-y]=C-E[x]+E[y]$, where C is a constant.

I know this formula is correct, but I'm wondering if there are parentheses surrounding the expected symbol, that is：

$C-E[x-y]=C-(E[x-y])$.

So the parenthese is omitted?

Comment: What is wrong with omitting the parentheses?

Comment: Even more, why would you put parentheses around $E[x-y]$, this is already one block ... like you wouldn't write $C - (1)$ ...